# Mi sistema no cuenta las consonantes

Tags: java, bucle-for

queria hacerles una consulta, estoy practicando programacion en java e hice un sistema que me cuenta las vocales y consonantes, desgraciadamente cuenta solo las vocales y no se por que, espero puedan ayudarme ( adjunto codigo )

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication152;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Kenneth
 */
public class JavaApplication152 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String letra, vocabulario = "aeiou"; 
        int Vocal = 0, espaciosconsonante = 0, acumulaconsona = 0;
        System.out.println(" Digita el nombre a evaluar ");
        letra = leer.next();
        String [] vectorpalabra = new String [letra.length()];
        String [] reservapalavra =  new String [letra.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<letra.length(); i++)
        {

            for(int v=0; v<vocabulario.length(); v++)
            {

                if(letra.charAt(i) == vocabulario.charAt(v))
                {
                    Vocal++;
                }
                if(!(letra.charAt(i) == vocabulario.charAt(v)))
                {
                    espaciosconsonante++;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(" La palabra a examinar es "+letra+ "  y tiene un total de "+Vocal+" vocales y un total de "+espaciosconsonante+" consonantes "); 
    }
}
```

Comment: El código no compila y no es completo, edita para ver lo que tienes.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de editar el código.

Answer (score 1):

Cuentas mal las consonantes (esto ya lo sabías). Por cada iteración del bucle de vocales (aeiou) si la letra de turno es vocal te suma 4 consonantes, si es consonante - 5.

Prueba esto:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < letra.length(); i++) {
            for (int v = 0; v < vocabulario.length(); v++) {
                if (letra.charAt(i) == vocabulario.charAt(v)) {
                    Vocal++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    espaciosconsonante++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Aunque este código necesita rehacerse casi por completo - es todo menos eficaz.

Answer (score 0):

A continuación se actualizó el código para contar solamente las vocales, las consonantes se las halla con la diferencia entre la longitud de la palabra y el número de vocales, este ejemplo es aplicable cuando no se ingresan números ni caracteres especiales:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letra, vocabulario = "aeiou";
        int Vocal = 0;
        System.out.println(" Digita el nombre a evaluar ");
        letra = leer.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < letra.length(); i++) {
            for (int v = 0; v < vocabulario.length(); v++) {
                if (letra.charAt(i) == vocabulario.charAt(v)) {
                    Vocal++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" La palabra a examinar es " + letra
                + "  y tiene un total de " + Vocal + " vocales y un total de "
                + (letra.length() - Vocal) + " consonantes ");

    }
```

Este ejemplo fue con la palabra **"estacionamiento"** y el resultado fue el siguiente:

> La palabra a examinar es estacionamiento  y tiene un total de 8 vocales y un total de 7 consonantes

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, sos un genio !!